# In iPhone, can I create a link to a page of podcast on iTunes Store?

Tags: iphone, ios

In bottom of podcast title list of Apple's Music app, there is a link(`Get More Episodes...`) to the page of the podcast on iTunes Store.

Can I do same thing in my app?

**EDIT**

I'm getting podcast from ipod library of iphone by using MediaPlayer framework.

**EDIT**

I found two related questions. 
Both of them says there is no way to get iTunes ID from MPMediaItem in iPod Library.

[Is there a way to retrieve iTunes Persistent ID on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4620967/is-there-a-way-to-retreive-itunes-persistent-id-on-iphone)

[Obtaining iTunes ID to an iPod player item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983461/obtaining-itunes-id-to-an-ipod-player-item)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

```
-(IBAction)pushToAppleStore
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://itunes.apple.com/gb/tv-season/episode-1/id545306665?i=547954947"]];
}
```

Comment: thanks. To use that url, I have to know id(`id545306665 `). How can I know the id of podcast which my app's user selected?

Comment: How are you getting the original pod cast in the first place? I got the link from itunes on the desk top just right click on it and copy URL or if it's particular episode you want just click the button on the right of the price or the word free and copy link.

Comment: I'm getting podcast from ipod library of iphone by using MediaPlayer framework.

Comment: Not something I've had to do before, so can't help on that one.

Comment: thanks anyway. Your answer was helpful because I also wanted to know how to open url. And the name of the method (-`pushTo`AppleStore) is nice. I added information about the id(iTunes ID).